# Python how to remove unwanted substring in a string

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I have this column in my dataset with that contains the following data sample:

| player |
| --- |
| David Johnson*+\JohnDa08 |
| Kareem Hunt*\HuntKa00 |
| Melvin Gordon\GordMe00 |

and I'm trying to make it look like this using Python:

| player |
| --- |
| David Johnson |
| Kareem Hunt |
| Melvin Gordon |

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In Python when you have a `str` and you want to remove a substring you can use the `.replace` method:

```
>>> a = "Hello!"
>>> a.replace("Hello", '')
'!'
>>> a = a.replace("Hello", '')
```

---

In your case the most simple thing to do is this:

```
>>> s = "Kareem Hunt*\\HuntKa00"
>>> s = s.replace("*\\", ' ').replace("00", '')
```

Or, to be more sure about the `00` to be removed from the back of the string:

```
>>> s = s.replace("*\\", ' ').removesuffix("00")
```

---

Since your strings are not all ending with `00` but some others are ending for example with `08`, I would suggest this:

```
>>> s = s.replace("*\\", ' ')[:-2]
```

which excludes the last two characters from the string

Answer (score 0):

You can `split` on the first special character and get the first chunk:

```
df['player'] = df['player'].str.split(r'[^\w ]', n=1).str[0]
```

Or, using `replace`:

```
df['player'] = df['player'].str.replace(r'[^\w ].*$', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
          player
0  David Johnson
1    Kareem Hunt
2  Melvin Gordon
```